# How to set default value on a tables model that extends a seperate tables model as it's base in SQL Alchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I've had a good dig around various questions and seem to be missing something that I feel must be fairly obvious.

**In Postgres, using Python, SQLAlchemy and FactoryBoy to run (now failing) tests, I have two table models...**

- File
- Letter

When `Letter` is instantiated, it extends `File`:

`class Letter(File):`

--

and `File` in turn extends SQL Alchemys `DeclarativeBase`:

`class File(DeclarativeBase):`

--

Within `File`, is a property called `content_type`.

`content_type` has now been set on `File` to be `not nullable`.

--

**What I need to do feels very basic...**

Within `Letter`, I need to set the default `content_type` to `"application/pdf"`... **that's it!**

However, for all my trying, I cannot seem to get it to set this as the default content type for `Letter`

This means that tests we have running, fail on trying to create the `File` as it has no `content_type` to pass over to `File`, meaning I get a`NotNullViolation`.

I have tried setting this within the `Letter` model in a few different ways, but to no avail.

--

**Approaches:**

- I tried using `__init__` in both the Custom Base model of `File` and as well as in `Letter` using `kawgs` and attempting to set it that way, though this did not work.
- I have thought about adding the column into the `Letter` model, but this defeats Third Normal Form so I assume there is a better way to do it.
- I have attempted to pass the value through the test we are running but without any luck (tests are using `FactoryBoy`)
- There is a `LetterFactory` (from `FactoryBoy`) which is where the issue is coming from, I have attempted to add `content_type = "application/pdf"` to this without any luck.
- I have also attempt to set the `content_type` on the model return in the `FactoryBoy - LetterFactory`, again :

```
class Meta(SQLAlchemyOptions):
    model = Letter
    model.content_type = "application/pdf"
```

- Within the `Letter` model itself, I included the following, also without any luck:

```
@property
    def content_type(self):
        return "application/pdf"
```

--

Apologies on what I think might be a basic question.

Any pointers would be very welcomed.

It's perhaps just a case of me not being familiar with the right terminology in SQL Alchemy and missing the obvious.

Does anyone understand my issue and have any threads they could give me to pull on?

Comment: Dunno if it'd work, but have a go with declared attrs - https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.declared_attr

Comment: No joy unfortunately, seems to thinks `declared_attrs` is not declared, would it only work in Mixins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me, I must have got something wrong initially:

File(Base):

```
...
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
...
```

Letter(File):

```
...
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault("content_type", "application/pdf")
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
...
```